# Get file name & path from cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have below code which will export worksheet as .CSV file. It will create new file with .CSV format with current file name & on current locations.

Want to modify it in a way it should pick file name to be save from cell N15 & it should get saved in pre defined path.

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
 End With        

Dim Change below to "- 4"  to become compatible with .xls files
MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, 
Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, 
CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value from your File Name Variable

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()

    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     End With        

    Dim Change below to "- 4"  to become compatible with .xls files
    MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Range("N15").value2

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, 
    CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Also one more thing which I noticed that code will work only for current workbook. Can we define workbook name ? That defined workbook will get export.

Comment: I'm new to this field & over here

Comment: Sure , Change Range() for , Worksheets("YOUR_WORKBOOK").range("N15").value2

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It work very well. Saved tons of my time.

Comment: I have made below changes. Active workbook.sheets("Final") & replace range() with current events.worksheets("Final").range.("R1") & ".CSV". This code is working fine. It will export Final sheet as CSV with name from cell R1. But it will export it to my documents. Is there any way we can put export path. I have tried currentwb.path but didn't work for me. Please suggest.